# Tox InvocationError (exited with code 1) when running pytest

Tags: pytest, tox

I am using Python 3.7.4, pytest 6.2.5, tox 3.24.4.
Is it an expected behavior that pytest failure will cause tox command (wrap around the pytest) exited with code 1? Appreciate your insights.

Command as follows indicated in Jenkins console log:

```
foobar run-test: commands[0] | pytest test_foobar.py
```

Error below:

```
InvocationError for command /path/.tox/foobar/bin/pytest test_foobar.py (exited with code 1)
```

Here is the tox.ini file.

```
[tox]
envlist = foobar,xxx
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
basepython = python3.7
passenv = *

[testenv:foobar]
deps =
    -r requirements.txt
commands =
    pytest {posargs}

[testenv:xxx]
envdir = {toxworkdir}/foobar
deps = 
    {[testenv:foobar]deps}
commands =
    <something> {posargs}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an addition to `phd`s correct answer, that `tox` returns non-zero when one of the commands failed...

If you really need a successful `tox` run although a command fails, you can prepend it with a dash.

e.g.

```
[testenv:foobar]
deps =
    -r requirements.txt
commands =
    - pytest {posargs}
```

See https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-commands

Answer (score 2):

From the docs at https://tox.wiki/en/latest/index.html

> Only if all environments ran successfully tox will return exit code 0 (success).

I.e., yes, it is an expected behavior that `pytest` failure will cause `tox` command exited with code 1.